# how to call .net pagemodel onpost method using jquery ready function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I've a onpost method in .net core pagemodel class like below

```
 public void  OnPostLoad(string TZ)
    {         
       ///..statements..////
    }
```

and i need to call the above method from my razor page - jquery ready function
i've tried like below but it's not worked for me

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.post(base_url+"/Transactions/Index?handler=Load="+{TZ:timezone }, response => {  
              
                alert("test timezone");
            });
            });
```

please let me know if you have any solutions for it. thanks

Comment: Change to `base_url + "/Transactions/Index?handler=Load&TZ=" + timezone` check how to pass url parameters: https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/

Comment: hi Dimitris , this solution returns error 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request Verification is baked into the Razor Pages framework. If you use ajax to post data, it needs anti-forgery token verification.

1.If your page contains form. The form tag helper injects a hidden form field named `__RequestVerificationToken` at the end of every form with an encrypted value representing the token. You just need add headers for this token:

```
<form method="post">
    //...
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var timezone = "aaa";
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                }
            });
            $.post(base_url+"/Transactions/Index?handler=Load&TZ=" + timezone ,response => {                   
                alert("test timezone");
            });
         });
    </script>
}
```

2.If your page does not contain any form, you can turn off anti-forgery token verification and then you no need add `RequestVerificationToken` header any more:

In ASP.NET 6

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

In ASP.NET Core 3.x or .NET 5

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

3.If your page does not contain form and you also do not want to turn off anti-forgery token verification, you can automatically add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var timezone = "aaa";
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                }
            });
            $.post(base_url+"/Transactions/Index?handler=Load&TZ=" + timezone ,response => {                    
                alert("test timezone");
            });
         });
    </script>
}
```